# jQuery Animate - No animation when the page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, animation

I am having an issue with jQuery animate on an iPad Mini (Safari).

I run the following animation when a button is clicked:

```
$('body').on('click', '#submitBtn', function () {
    $('#loadBar').animate({ width: '95%' }, 8000);
});
```

This button sends a request that makes the page reload. As it is starting to reload I want the loadBar to animate.

This does not happen as no animation is fired.

It works if you add return false; and stop the page reload from occurring.

Are there any ways around this. I have tried CSS3 animations and get the same issue.

The animation must occur at the same time as the submit event.

Thanks!

Comment: where is your html???

Comment: I can't post the functionality for the request I am afraid as I don't have access to it (back-end code). It is literally a button with an ID of 'submitBtn'. I attach the above event to it. It is to show the progress of the request. The request is not ajax based either.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the page in js after the animation completes

```
$('body').on('click', '#submitBtn', function () {
    $('#loadBar').animate({ width: '95%' }, 8000, function(){
        window.location.reload();
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I can't do this as the request is made to a 3rd party I believe. The url does not change so the location would be the exact same page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its a submit form with id "myform":

```
$('body').on('click', '#submitBtn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loadBar').animate({ width: '95%' }, 8000, function() {
        $( "#myform" ).submit();
    });
});
```

EDIT :

Check `beforeunload()` in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    $('#loadBar').animate({ width: '95%' }, 8000);
});
```

Comment: It is a form but I need the animation to occur at the same time as the submission.

Comment: I see. So you could use onbeforeunload() right? i guess it is better suited for what you need. i will change the answer here.

Comment: Let me know if beforeunload() didn't work for you. I made a local test here and (if i understood what you want) it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2v0s6oIw8jNn8BmoTemi?p=preview

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#submitBtn', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $('#loadbar').animate({ width: '95%' }, 8000);
      setTimeout(function(){ //remove this line
        $("#form").submit();
      }, 5000); //simulate slow loading page. remove this line 
    });
 });
```

The idea here is that you prevent the default behavior of the browser, force it to animate, and then continue the submit.

Comment: All JS is stopped when the submit event is triggered. At 5 seconds the animation will halt. It will never finish.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But do you know how long your submit page will take to load? If not, then setting the animation time to 8 seconds of course will get interrupted. At least I'd hope so, 8 seconds is a long time for a user!

Comment: Also, the timeout was simply to simulate a slow loading page. Remove the lines as commented.